# How to use ajax with Wordpress plugin for filtering?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have drop-down element, and on selection of one item I need to query from database and to show me result in second drop-down.

I have several drop-down, I need to narrow the filter.

I have to do it with ajax, but I am new in this. Where should i write query statement and which path to put in URL

because I am doing it in WP, do I always have to do use url: admin-ajax.php default in WP?

```
//dropDownKlix ajax call
    jQuery("#dropDownKlix").change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'admin-ajax.php',
            data: {"name":"name","value":$("#dropDownKlix option:selected").val()},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success!');
            }
        });
    });
```

this is my ajax request, but I dont know where to put sql statement to filter and retrive data to show in another drop-down.

Should I put in callback query or ?

If you need more information, please ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is my ajax request, but I dont know where to put sql statement to filter and retrive data to show in another drop-down.

You should use the `wp_ajax_{action}` hook to create a custom handler for your AJAX request.

In your AJAX request, you should set the action property to `{action}`. For example:

**AJAX request example:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'action' : 'your_action',
        'name' : 'name',
        'value' : $( '#dropDownKlix option:selected' ).val()

    },
    success:function( data ) { ...
```

**Custom handler example:**

```
function my_handler() {
    // Handle the request then generate a response.
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_action', 'my_handler' );
```

If you want to handle requests from unauthorised users on the front-end, then use `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}`

For more detailed info, see the [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) article.

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)